# Why do my images show at designtime and not at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF `<Image>` that I am trying to display on a `<Button>` inside of a `<Toolbar>` with the following code.

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar Height="26" Name="toolBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Button Name="StampButton" Click="StampButton_Click">
            <Image Source="/MyApp.Resources;component/Resources/MyImage.png" 
            Height="16" Width="16" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

The image shows up just fine at design time. However, at runtime nothing is displayed. The resources are in another dll called `MyApp.Resources`. The button is actually created just fine and the click event works fine also.

Answer (score 1):

Set your image build action to "Resource". Try to use full source path.

Comment: The image is set to build action Resource and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem - image displaying at design time, but not at runtime.
I had build action set to resource, tried different pack uris etc etc, but solution was simple

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="your_image_key" UriSource="your_image.png" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource your_image_key}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, from a site called wpf-tutorial.com:

`<Image Source="/WpfTutorialSamples;component/Images/copy.png" />`

Images is a subfolder of the project folder in my case, and I assume also in this sample.